# Trigger Help: Capture user from custom object (ticket) and assign task to user (task object)

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I am very new to apex coding. Please see trigger below which creates a task when a ticket is raised with priority high. The trigger works except for this line : // t.Owner = Tickets__c.Assigned_To__c;

I am trying to pick up the the user to whom the ticket is assigned via field Assigned_To__c in the custom ticket object and then create a task where the owner of the task is the same user as the 'Assigned to' field captures in the ticket object.

### What do I need to do to pick up the user captured in a field (Assigned to) in a custom object (ticket) and then assign the same user as owner of a task?

Trigger compiles except for the commented line:

trigger AssignTicket on Tickets__c (after insert,after update) {

```
for(Tickets__c tkt : trigger.new){

if(tkt.Priority__c == 'High'){

task t = new task();

t.Subject = 'Ticket has been assigned to you!';
t.Status = 'Not Started';
t.Priority = 'Normal';
//t.Owner = Tickets__c.Assigned_To__c.; **[Need help with this line]**

t.WhatId = tkt.id;

       insert t;
                            }


                                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the insert out of the loop and set OwnerID, not Owner.

```
List<Task> lInsert = new List<Task>();
for(Tickets__c tkt : trigger.new){

if(tkt.Priority__c == 'High'){

task t = new task();

t.Subject = 'Ticket has been assigned to you!';
t.Status = 'Not Started';
t.Priority = 'Normal';
t.OwnerID = Tickets__c.Assigned_To__c.; **[Need help with this line]**

t.WhatId = tkt.id;

lInsert.Add(t);
 }
}
insert lInsert;
```